# Returning a string via jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I'm writing a simple API client interface with Jackson, and I'm trying to return a string.

My other data objects returned were JSON, so I had:

```
@Path("api-server")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
```

But for this particular one:

```
@GET
@Path("/ping/{echoString}")
public String ping(@PathParam("echoString") String echo);
```

I'm expecting a String and not a JSON object. How can I make it so that I get a "not 200 error problem", mainly because it doesn't understand the data type returned, which is a string (not a JSON object).

Comment: 2XX HTTP status codes denote a successful request. Can you be more specific about the error you're seeing? If you want to produce a plain text response you can always add @Produces("text/plain").

Comment: Sorry I meant it's not 200.

Comment: What specific response code is being returned? 415 Unsupported Media Type?

Comment: When I debug it, it fails at 415 Unsupported Media Type, yes.

Comment: If you add @Produces("text/plain") and @Consumes("text/plain") to the method does that resolve the issue? If you don't control the API itself, it might be useful to call it manually (via curl or something), and ensure that media type annotations you specify align with the content-type header returned from the server.